# Compile a C++ function inside a C++ program

Tags: c++, llvm, jit

Consider the following problem,

A C++ program may emit source of a C++ function, for example, say it will create a string with contents as below:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<C>> get_ptr_vec()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<C>> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::shared_ptr<C>(new C(val1)));
    vec.push_back(std::shared_ptr<C>(new C(val2)));
    vec.push_back(std::shared_ptr<C>(new C(val3)));
    vec.push_back(std::shared_ptr<C>(new C(val4)));
    return vec;
}
```

The values of `val1` etc will be determined at runtime when the program create the string of the source above. And this source will be write to a file, say `get_ptr_vec.cpp`.

Then another C++ program will need to read this source file, and compile it, and call the `get_ptr_vec` function and get the object it returns. Kind of like a JIT compiler.

Is there any way I can do this? One workaround I think would be having a script that will compile the file, build it into a shared library. And the second program can get the function through `dlopen`. However, is there anyway to skip this and having the second program to compile the file (without call to `system`). Note that, the second program will not be able to see this source file at compile time. In fact, there will be likely thousands such small source files emitted by the first program.

To give a little background, the first program will build a tree of expressions, and will serialize the tree by traversing through postorder. Each node of tree will have a string representation written to the file. The second program will read the list of this serialized tree nodes, and need to be able to reconstruct this list of strings to a list of C++ objects (and later from this list I can reconstruct the tree).

I think the LLVM framework may have something to offer here. Can someone give me some pointers on this? Not necessary a full answer, just somewhere for me to start.

Comment: This is very close to -Should be closed:  _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: Yeah, we generally don't do this. We might generate C++ from a Python script, or even from a C++ program, but the result always gets piped through to a compiler proper.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use some kind of serialization library for this? [Boost::Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) maybe?

Comment: @KarlReid Normally yes. But the problem is that every element to be serialized will actually be functions instead of some objects with concrete values.

Comment: Fair enough. Depending on the complexity of the operations, maybe you could create a simple domain specific language and generate/parse that, as another idea.

Comment: Sounds like you want a DLL?

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your generated code with clang and emit LLVM bitcode (`-emit-llvm` flag). Then, statically link your program with parts of LLVM that read bitcode files and JITs them. Finally, take compiled bitcode and run JIT on them, so they will be available in your program's address space.